# Execute SQL functions with Laravel 5

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel

I have SQL functions stored on my database.

However, I can not call them.

```
$nb = DB::select('SELECT nb_seances_archivees()');
```

The result is :

```
array:1 [▼
   0 => {#186 ▼
      +"nb_seances_archivees": 0
   }
]
```

But the desired result is just `0`.

Thank's for help !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default `DB::select` return an array of objects, you can use [collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections) to get the first result:

```
 $nb = collect(DB::select('SELECT nb_seances_archivees() AS nb'))->first()->nb;
```

**Or** directly access the first object in the array:

```
 $nb = DB::select('SELECT nb_seances_archivees() AS nb')[0]->nb;
```

If you want to pass parameters then you should do:

```
 DB::select('SELECT nb_seances_archivees(?) AS nb', [$parameter]);
```

Comment: And what is `DB::table('table')` (because functions are not specific at a table)?

Comment: Just use: `\DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT nb_seances_archivees()'));`

Comment: With `DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT nb_seances_archivees()'));` I get the same result and not `0`.

Comment: Sorry I Thought your query is not working, I updated my answer, take a look

Comment: Thank's a lot! What solution do you recommend?

Comment: You are welcome, I think the second one is simple, there is no need to instantiate a collection class, If my answer works for you, you may want to accept it,

Comment: And if I need to use parameters into my function, do you know how thats works?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161229/discussion-between-younel-and-n-lamblin).

Comment: i am going to use this query in front of eloquent query but i am getting syntax error 1064,$this->petterns_query()->select(DB::select('levenshtein_ratio(?,?) AS results', ["comfortcontact,", 'name']))->get()